# How do I flash a custom recovery/ROM to my Galaxy Core Prime (SM-G360V)?

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, odin, heimdall, samsung-galaxy-core-prime

I've been trying to flash a custom recovery and ROM to an old Galaxy Core Prime. Based on advice I received on Reddit, I decided to try using Heimdall. I put the phone into Odin Mode and connected it to the computer. I then attempted to create a PIT file for my device, in order to flash the TWRP .TAR file to it. The process started, before I received the following error message:

> Downloading device's PIT file...
>
> ERROR: Failed to send request to end PIT file transfer!
>
> ERROR: Failed to download PIT file!
>
> Ending session...
>
> ERROR: Failed to send end session packet!
>
> Releasing device interface...

I don't know what happened. What went wrong? How do I fix this issue? If needed, here are some clearer photos showing my situation:
[image: Screenshot of Heimdall]

[image: Photo of Galaxy Core Prime in Odin Mode]

Comment: please try again with another fork of heimdall (precompiled binaries available) https://github.com/amo13/Heimdall/releases